# how to get specific date in time series in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I want to make a forecast project from a time series dataframe.
but, the time span is too big.
then, I have this column in dataframe from a time series data frame.

```
Date
2010-06-29
2010-06-30
2010-07-01
2010-07-02
```

how can I change it so that it only shows every 7 days?

```
Date
2010-06-29
2010-07-05
2010-07-12
2010-07-19
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataframe.new = dataframe[seq(1, nrow(dataframe), 7),]
```

seq documentation - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq

basically, seq(1, 100, 7) will generate - 1, 8, 15, ...

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is very simple and direct.
However, it will return only data from a specified weekday, which could lead to biased results depending on the nature of your data.

You can create an index of weekdays that is balanced with random sampling of weekdays:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from = ymd("2021/01/01"), 
                                 to = ymd("2021/12/31"),
                                 by = "day"))

#create index by sampling weekdays randomly

set.seed(1)
index<-replicate(floor(nrow(df)/7), {sample(unique(df$weekday), replace = FALSE)}) %>% 
        as.vector()

#subsetting to a 7-fold smaller dataset

library(dplyr)

output<-df %>% filter(weekdays(date)==index)

#checking table of weekdays in the final dataset

table(output$weekday)

   Friday    Monday  Saturday    Sunday  Thursday   Tuesday Wednesday 
       13         6         5         9         8        10         6
```

Comment: If OP wants to deviate from the fixed interval subsetting that they mention in the question(e.g. every 7 days), they might as well just take a simple uniform sample across all the dates (unless there is a need to have exactly one value per week. If there needs to be one value per week, then `df %>% group_by(week = lubridate::week(date)) %>% sample_n(1)` would do the job as well.